# Intellij - RUn vs debug issues

Tags: java, intellij-idea, static

When I run(<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>), the Java application runs,
however when I debug (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>), the application fails. 
Basically, the application which I am running/debugging extends a parent class which has an init clause which looks for a property.

```
class A extends B{
static{
  // I init. the property here
}

}

class B {
 public static void main(){
    //looks for the property i init, and if it doesn't find it, fails
 }
}
```

During the RUN, it works fine, the static block gets invoked first, however during the Debug, the static block is not invoked. Why?
And I have a breakpoint in the static block-doesn't even reach there.

Intellij 12.4 Ultimate, JDK 1.6.0.18,make before run.

Comment: This seems to be a little backwards, why is the parent looking for a property of its child?

Comment: Its kind of a framework loader,the property is actually location of a config file, which is loaded in the classpath by the superclass